# PowerShell still locks the file after the end of a script that sends email with attachment

Tags: powershell, mailmessage

I'm using PowerShell and `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` to create email body with an attachment. I found after the end of my script and the email is sent successfully, the target file is still occupied by PowerShell until I exit PowerShell. Is there any way to "close" it like closing file pointer in C or Python?

Here is the code of how I create mail message and send it:

```
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $sender, $mailTo
$message.Subject = "Test email with attachment"
$message.Body = "See attachment."
$message.Attachments.Add("path\to\file")

$smtpClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpHostname, $smtpPort)
$smtpClient.EnableSSL = $true
$smtpClient.send($message)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [`System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Net.Mail.MailMessage) and [`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient) implement the [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) interface, which means you can - and should<sup>[1]</sup> - call the `.Dispose()` method on their instances to make them release all resources they may be using once you're done:

```
$message.Dispose()
$smtpClient.Dispose()
```

---

<sup>[1] If you neglect to do so, the resources held will *eventually* be released, namely the next time .NET's garbage collector runs, but the timing of that isn't predictable.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does resolve my issue.

Comment: I appreciate it, @ytingyeu.